# Chrome Save and Open With Settings

Tags: google-chrome

I searched on the net but I couldn't find something useful for open zip files with out saving or torrent files direct open with Utorrent. I can have this access on Internet Explorer, Opera, Firefox but on Chrome, I can only save files. But I want to open them directly. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, Google Chrome **[doesn't not support opening files without downloading them](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/Drge_Zrwg-c)**.
For `.torrent` files, the above link provides an acceptable workaround.